# Slicing a list in java

Tags: java, list, selenium-webdriver

I have a list which I get from the selenium-webdriver:

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(""));
```

Now I want to get the first 6 elements and print them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use condition to check the for loop iteration something like,

```
int i=1;
for(WebElement element: allElements){
if(i==6)
break; //break the loop
system.out.println(""+element.getText());
i++;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

A different and concise way to do that is using [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) from Java 8:

```
List<WebElement> subElements = allElements.stream().limit(6).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Please note that there is also `skip()` in streams. `skip()` and `limit()`are friends that go good together.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`List#sublist()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-):

```
System.out.println(allElements.subList(0, 6));
```

Or, since you're using Webdriver, you also have Google Guava (it's a transitive dependency), so [`Iterables.limit()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#limit(java.lang.Iterable,%20int)) also works and it's arguably slightly more readable and doesn't fail when the list is too short:

```
System.out.println(Iterables.limit(allElements, 6));
```

Comment: `subList` returns a list of reference to the original list items. It does not make a copy.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways and one of them is below:

```
for(int i=0; i < 6; i++) {
    WebElement element =  allElements.get(i);
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this increment i twice...?

Comment: I tried it ,and my code is working,as i wanted it to.